# On window resize do not modify width or height on any element of body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is possible to do something like: when the browser is resized I dont' want to alterate width and height to any element of body. 
I hava a large table in my page and when I resize I want to have the same width or height as when was loaded in full browser mode.

Comment: As a matter of interest, why do you want to do this? What kind of content is inside the table?

Comment: this is the page: http://mainpage.ueuo.com/

Comment: Personally I think you should determine what a good, readable width is and set it to that always.  If the user has a strangely shaped browser window upon visiting the page, they're going to get a really strangely sized table and they wont be able to fix that without refreshing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just give your table a fixed width and height. With min-width and min-height it will still resize untill it matches the defined minimum width and height

```
table
{
    width:500px;
}
```

the width might not be a problem but you never know the height of a table, this can change a lot so with jQuery you can do the following:

```
var myTable = $('.table');
var myTableHeight = myTable.height();
myTable.css('height', myTableHeight);
```

EDIT:
Based on  your comment this is what you could do. You leave the 200% but the first time the browser loads you get the width of the table and set it as fixed width. It will then always stay the same.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
//once the document was completely loaded get the width of the table and se it as fixed width
    var myTable = $('.table');
    var myTableWidth = myTable.width();
    myTable.css('width', myTableWidth);
});
</script>
```

Comment: my table has 200% with overflow-x: auto; :) I cannot use fixed size defined in px

Comment: the only way to make sure it doesn't resize is to set a fixed width. but if you set it to a percentage it will of course resize. This is default behaviour. It will always set it to 200% based on your browser width and height. You either use percentage or pixels and pixels is the only way to get a fixed with, certainly not percentage. You could check the width of the browser the first time it loads and then using jquery to set a fixed width. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Not working :((  check fiddle:    http://jsfiddle.net/Ksb2W/92/           I was thinking to something like: `$(window).resize(function(){
    $("table").accordion("resize"); //do something
});`  I don't know if is really works  ....

Comment: Ok i update my answer. Obviously the #mytableid selector was just an example, you needed to change that to .table since your table has a class table. and .getWidth() doesn't seem to work for some reason but you can always just use .width().

Comment: Oh yes, I was wrong when I copy and paste in fiddle example but on my project I used my id's when I testes your script :)

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS `min-width` and `min-height`.

Comment: Only good if you know what the fixed width/height will be in advance

Comment: this will create problems on various machines resolutions ... with jQuery is possible to calculate initial size(width and height) and to keep that.